# Is the second Alternate Character View only avaliable after getting the Wakaba Ending

Tags: katahane

I'm following this [Walkthrough](http://tlwiki.org/index.php?title=Katahane:Walkthrough) for Katahane, i'm doing the Angelina ending because i brought the game purely to see the romance between Angelina and Belle however i do plan to get the Wakaba and Coco Endings after (since i'm a completionist)

When i got to the first Alternate Character View, i switched over to Light like it said (the other being Wakaba which you stick with if you go for the Wakaba Ending), however, i never got the second Alternate Character View

so i am wondering, does the second Alternate Character View only appear if i got the Wakaba Ending?

Comment: Uh, just saying, when I read you "bought the game purely to see the romance between Angelina and Belle", I thought, 'wow, maybe a little too honest here man' :)

Comment: @TheUgly when i say romance i mean Angelina and Belle meeting, falling in love, stuff like that, i can avoid the H Scenes easily using a separate system bit it's too long winded for me to explain how it works (not to mention i didn't create it, a friend did), anyway, there's no problem with loving Shoujo Ai/Yuri

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: @TheUgly none taken, sorry if i sounded like i did take any but you are right, i'm honest with myself in loving Shoujo Ai/Yuri, just not for the same reasons as most people i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Completing what i think is the Angelina Ending and going though it again and the Wakaba Ending i have found all Another Character View that come right after a previous one only appear after you see the end credits once

I say "see the end credits once" as i am unsure if what i saw was the Angelina Ending as it seemed a bit abrupt and even with how Wakaba ended it seem to conclude Angelina and Belle better so i am unsure if i've seen the Angelina Ending on my first playthough